# I want to print key and value as key and value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have json data in the below format

```
{
  "Development": 33,
  "Automation Testing": 25,
  "Manual Testing": 15,
  "Reporting": 17,
  "PM": 10
}
```

and i want to print "Development" and "33" on view using angularjs .how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this
on you html

```
 <ul ng-repeat="(key, prop) in yourjson_array">
   <li>{{key}}{{prop}}</li>
 <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```